# How to check if there are no elements/tags inside another element/tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have search all over Stack Overflow site but I can find an answer

The code below is not show any alert when there is no more `<tr>` in `<tbody>`, why is that?

I'm sure the below should work but nothing happens:

```
<script>
  $('td > a').click(function(e){
  var this_elem = $(this);

  if( this_elem.hasClass("remove") ){
    this_elem.parent().parent().remove();
  }

  return false;

 });

 if( $("tbody > tr").length === 0 ){

  alert("No more rows of products...");

 }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="first-td">
    <img src="assets/product-image.jpg" alt="product image" />

    <div class="prod-desc-col">
     <h3>Samsung LE40C580J1 LCD HD 1080p Digital Television, 40 Inch with Built-in Freeview HD, Samsung LE40C580J1 LCD HD 1080p Digital Television, 40 Inch with Built-in Freeview HD</h3>
     <p>Product Code: 1254782</p>
     <p>In stock</p>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" value="1" size="4" />
    <a href="#" title="Update" class="update">Update</a>
    <a href="#" title="Remove" class="remove">Remove</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more information. Where is this code being called from?

Comment: @Karl Nicoll: it's called inside `<script`> in `<body>`. I have also updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not counting the *next* rows, you're counting *all* rows in the `tbody` in *all* the `table`s in your page.

Given the additional details added to the question, I offer you this:

```
$('a.remove').click(

function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // a slightly more concise form of your own code
    return false;
});

$('table tbody').bind('DOMNodeRemoved', function() {
    var c = $('table tbody tr').length;
    if (c === 1) { // testing against '1' because the count is performed before
                   // the row is actually removed from the DOM.
        alert("The final row is about to go.");
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yQULd/).

Comment: @David Thomas: There is only 1 table on the page. But I just wanna alert the user when  tbody is empty...

Comment: @Shaoz, are you removing the `tr`s or just iterating over them for some reason? If you edit your question to add the relevant details then I imagine we can help. =)

Comment: @David Thomas: I'm removing each `tr` with a 'remove' link/button. Then when there is no more `tr`, an alert box appears to inform that there no more `tr`. NB: I've just updated the question with more info.

Comment: @shaoz, please check the edit, and [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yQULd/) I think it should be what you're looking for, albeit only tested in Chrome 8.x on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: @David Thomas: Yeaahhh, it works. Thanks you very much David... The problem was that I was performing the check in the wrong time... Interesting... But thanks a lot though.

Comment: @Shaoz, no problem at all; glad to be of help =)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have only one table in the page? Otherwise you are counting all rows in all tables in the page.

To count the rows that way works, you can see my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/2DDZz/

### Edit:

As you posted the code, I see that you are only checking the number of rows when the page loads. You should check it each time that you have removed a row:

```
$('td > a').click(function(e){
  var this_elem = $(this);
  if( this_elem.hasClass("remove") ){
    this_elem.parent().parent().remove();

    if( $("tbody > tr").length === 0 ){
      alert("No more rows of products...");
    }

  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, only 1 table on the page.

Comment: @Shaoz: The problem is not that the code doesn't work, the problem is that you only run it once. You should do the check after removing a row. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information for us, but my first guess is that your JQuery selector looks for rows in ANY table on your page. It's possible that if you have any other tables in your page, those rows are being counted too. What you need to do is make your JQuery selector more specific. For example:

```
if( $(" #myTableName > tbody > tr").length === 0 ){
    alert("No more rows of products...");
}
```

Notice that I have added an ID to the selector. This tells JQuery to only look for rows in the table with an ID of "`myTableName`".

Comment: Forgot to mention that there's only table on the page so I didn't put an 'id' on it. So it should still work...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should look into using `nextAll`

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/